# Are google-play-services.jar and google-play-services_lib the Same Thing?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have inherited an Android project and I am just trying to get it to compile. I have downloaded all "Google Play ..." items through Android SDK Manager and have `google-play-services.jar` included in my project.

I am getting an error regarding `@integer/google_play_services_version`, but everything I am reading is talking about `google-play-services_lib`, not `google-play-services.jar`

Are `google-play-services.jar` and `google-play-services_lib` the same thing? If not, can someone tell me where I can get `google-play-services_lib`?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> everything I am reading is talking about google-play-services_lib, not google-play-services.jar

That is because the Play Services SDK is an Android library project, not just a JAR.

> Are google-play-services.jar and google-play-services_lib the same thing?

No.

> If not, can someone tell me where I can get google-play-services_lib?

If you downloaded what you said, it is already on your hard drive, just not [properly attached to your project](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that I had to 'show package contents' on the Android Studio application and then drill down to sdk > extras > google > google_play_services > libproject > google-play-services_lib